# Renaming columns using column data from another dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, header, keyerror

I have two dataframes - an original file that looks like this:

```
Gene Symbol, 10555, 10529, 10519
Map7, .184, .026, .207
nan, .348, .041, .187
Cpm, .45, .278, .453
```

and a reference file that looks like this:

```
Experiment_Num, Microarray, Experiment_Name, Chip_Name
10555, Genechip, Famotidine-5d, RG230-2
10529, Genechip, Famotidine-3d, RG230-2
10519, MMchip, Dicyclomine-3d, R01
```

I am trying to merge them in a way that the header of the original file display the Experiment_Name rather than just the Experiment_Num as follows:

```
Gene symbol, Famotidine-5d, Famotidine-3d, Dicyclomine-3d
Map7, .184, .026, .207
nan, .348, .041, .187
Cpm, .45, .278, .453
```

My code is completely written using pandas and looks as follows:

```
 import pandas as pd

df = ('ftp://anonftp.niehs.nih.gov/drugmatrix/Differentially_expressed_gene_lists_directly_from_DrugMatrix/Affymetrix/Affymetrix_annotation.txt', sep='\t', dtype=str) 
# Reference file

df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().replace(df.set_index('Experiment').Compound_Name)
#Original File

df2
```

I tried to convert the columns of the original DF to it's series representation and then replace the old value which were the Experiment_Num. with the new Experiment_name retrieved from the reference DF, but keep getting

*KeyError: 'Experiment'*

I tried figuring out what could be causing a KeyError, but found that there are so many possibilities, none of which seems to fix my particular issue.

Thanks for the help if possible!

Troy